# how to parse an html source code

Tags: html, qt, parsing, xml-parsing, qxmlstreamreader

I'm trying to parse a html source code. this is the webpage **[address](https://www.instagram.com/p/BTwnRykl6EM/)** I'm trying to parse. I have wrote the code below but it doesn't work at the last step that I wanna pull-out content of meta:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.instagram.com/p/BTwnRykl6EM/")));
    QEventLoop event;
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();
    QString me = reply->readAll();
    QString x;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //qDebug()<<me;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    QXmlStreamReader reader(me);
    if(reader.readNextStartElement()){
        if(reader.name()=="html"){
            while (reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                if(reader.name()=="head"){
                    while (reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                        if(reader.name()=="meta" && reader.attributes().hasAttribute("property") && reader.attributes().value("property").toString()=="og:image")
                            x = reader.attributes().value("content").toString();
                        else{
                            qDebug()<<"why?";
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
        }
        else
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
    }
    qDebug()<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

and this part doesn't work:

```
if(reader.name()=="meta" && reader.attributes().hasAttribute("property") && reader.attributes().value("property").toString()=="og:image")
    x = reader.attributes().value("content").toString();
else{
    qDebug()<<"why?";
    reader.skipCurrentElement();
}
```

and prints

> why?

**what is wrong with my code?**

Comment: That page is in HTML, but you're trying to use an XML parser to parse it -- not gonna work, those are two different formats.

Comment: So what library should I use for html? @MrEricSir

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not a valid XML, so you can't use XML parsers. Options for HTML you can find [on this wiki page](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_HTML). 
Shortly, you can use Qt's Scribe framework or QtWebKit for automatic parsing and rendering HTML, or external libraries for manual parsing:

- [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) (Win, Mac, Linux)
- [htmlcxx](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/) (Win, Linux)
- [libhtml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libhtml/) (Linux)

**libxml2** and **libhtml** are C libraries, **htmlcxx** is C++ library, that allows build dom-tree and iterate through it.

Comment: Add the basic premise from the link to the answer in case the link becomes obsolete.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota, thanks for advice. I added more info to my answer